# Fixed height and width only for desktop

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to implement a Vimeo video however for it to show correctly on mobile etc I have to have it in the responsive share mode however on desktop/notebook etc we want to have it a fixed height and width- how can I do this?

**Responsive Code:**

```
<div class="align-center" style="margin-bottom:20px;"> // My own div
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="#" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="align-center btn btn-mod btn-large btn-color">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 000px) { .class {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Replace `000` with any size viewport. For example, setting it to 992px would account for most desktop screens and will "adapt" the new CSS rules you chose to include to whatever class you add when the viewport meets the minimum width of whatever you chose.

`...` for any features you want to have your class include. (`height:`, `width:`, etc.)